# Deleting a view and onclick opening it again, as if it is new - SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, model-view-controller, sapui5

I have a multiple View setup, a main View and then modules who are opened on button click after certain actions.

Right now the view is reset by me whenever its opened, but what I want to accomplish is, when the view is left, that its gone from the core and its initiated again as if it is opened for the first time.

I am not certain how, and I tried multiple things, none worked as I intended (`.destroy()`, `.removeAllContent()`, ... ).

Did I miss a function or is there a way to accomplish that?

**Some code:**

index.js (how the View is instantiated the first time, its not called a second time)

```
module.exports.Partner = function(place) {
    View = require('./app/js/suche.view');
    Bearbeiten = require('./app/js/bearbeiten.view');
    var ctrl = View.getController();
    ctrl.setPlace(ctrl, place);
    ctrl.setEditPlace(ctrl, place);
    ctrl.setCreatePlace(ctrl, place);
    sap.ui.getCore().byId('suche').placeAt(place);
    sap.ui.getCore().byId('suche').byId('searchBtn').attachPress(ctrl.nummerSearch, ctrl);
};
```

controller (how the View and the index.js is called)

```
handlePartnerSuche : function(){
        this.hideView(); //this is the main view
        var p = require('bit-js-business-partner');
        var partner_view = p.Partner('content');
        p.setCallbackForSchliessen(this, this.callbackForSchliessen);
  },
```

controller (callback function)

```
callbackForSchliessen: function(){
        this.showView();
    },
```

The second View (how its closed)

```
handleSchliessen : function () {
        var p = this.getView('suche');
        p.setVisible(false);

        this.callbackMethodSchliessen.call(this.callbackCtrlSchliessen);
    },
```

Comment: Could you pls add Code, so i can help you efficiently. I am curious since `.destroy()` should definitely destroy and remove the View of the core.

Comment: Thats true it removes it but when I click on the button again to open the view. Nothing happens and the View doesnt appear.

Comment: ye... how do you instantiate the view again... like i said some code would make my life much easier

Comment: are you making an ajax call to render the view the next time after it has been destroyed? That could be a solution..

Comment: and if that is not the case..then you can have a global variable which stores the view before it is destroyed and re-render the variable value on clicking the event.

Comment: I added some code for clarification

Comment: It seems you instantiate your view only once, therefore you don't see the view a second time after a destroy(). But taking a step back, what is the main reason why you want to destroy your views? It is much more beneficial for your users to load the view just once, and call it from memory upon a second request.

Comment: @Qualiture that is true, its only that I am loading an OData service everytime it opens, and I wanna close it with the view. and it should be called everytime the view comes. the onInit in the controller is unfortunately only called once though

Comment: Then why not call it in `onAfterRendering()` event handler, that is called every time the view is displayed

Comment: So the `onAfterRendering()` is called everytime I set the Visibility to true? That would be new to me but I guess I missed that

Comment: No, but you should never, ever display views by toggling Visibility. Use the Router for that

Comment: I wish I could use one, but my company doesnt want to use them for some weird reason. Why doesnt it surprise me that this is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned you cannot use the Router mechanism due to company restrictions -- *am really curious to know what these restriction are then ;-)* -- and toggle the `visibility` properties of the respective views instead.

In that case, I would trigger the OData service in the method where you set the view's visibility to visible, and (re)bind the ODataModel to that view.

From a performance perspective, I would not advise to destroy views from the core

Comment: The restrictions come from the weird set-up of the Framework. And they wantto use an Event Bus instead of the routing. Complicated and weird. Its an old company, that is pretty progressive but well^^